# How to Vertically Center Sorting Icons in a Table Header of Unknown Height Only Using CSS

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to figure out a way to vertically center sorting icons in the `<th>` of a table in an AngularJS application.  I've added a fiddle with each of the variations the table header might take, which includes columns unsorted, ascending sorted, and descending sorted, as well as the issue when some of the `th` text wraps, and some doesn't. This is an exact replica of the markup and classes I have available, and in the application it all works except for the vertical position of the icons.

I've tried a few tricks that have worked in the past like using transform, but can't get it to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ox2hahtn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add negative margin with the half of icon height.

your icons height is 19px so put `margin-top: -9.5px`

your `&.after , &.before` will become :

```css
&:before,
&:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  opacity: 0.4;

  margin-top:-9.5px
}
```

Comment: Note: if the root (html) font-size be different than what you set in table, this -9.5px will failed! as i wrote in my answer, its better to use compatible unit for it. (sample: https://jsfiddle.net/ox2hahtn/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a negative `margin-top` for sort icons, and as you used `font-size: 0.8rem;` for icons, you can add `margin-top: -.6rem;` in addition to that `top:50%` to make it vertically center as in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ox2hahtn/4/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle,

```
th {
      position: relative;
      padding-right: 12px; // Some space for sorting icons to be placed without overlapping header
      border: 1px solid grey; // Border to show space that arrows are being centered
       white-space: nowrap;
      &.sortable {
        cursor: pointer;
        &:before,
        &:after {
          position: absolute;
          right: 2px;
          font-family: FontAwesome;
          font-size: 0.8rem;
          opacity: 0.4;
          display: inline-block;
          height: 100%; 
          vertical-align: middle;

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also you can add to th {white-space: nowrap;}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the [`translatey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) function to shift the pseudo-elements up by half their height. See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ox2hahtn/6/) for a working example.